# Integrable monotonic functions

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f \in L^1(0,+\infty)$ is a monotonic function. Prove that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} x f(x)=0$.

Comment: Of course, the main issue is the existence of the limit. If the limit exists, then it must be zero. I guess that it suffices to prove that $\limsup_{x \to +\infty} x f(x)=0$.

Comment: when x goes to infinity,maybe we can start from -infinity to plus infinity,and because f(x) is always positive,it would canceal out each other  right yes?

Comment: Well, the function is not defined on the whole real line. I think the solution should be more... tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can assume WLOG that $f$ is decreasing. Then $f$ is non-negative, otherwise, if $f(x_0)<0$ then $f(x)\leq f(x_0)<0$ for $x\geq x_0$ and $f$ wouldn't be integrable. We can write 
$$|xf(2x)|=\left|\int_x^{2x}f(2x)dt\right|=\int_x^{2x}f(2x)dt\leq \int_x^{2x}f(t)dt=\int_0^{2x}f(t)dt-\int_0^xf(t)dt.$$
Since $f$ is integrable, the RHS converges to $0$, so $\lim_{x\to 0}2xf(2x)=0$ and we are done.

Comment: This is a really nice proof: elementary and yet tricky! I think that a more standard proof could be found, based on something like Riemann sums and "limsup" estimates. But yours is surely better than this.